# how to add image instead of label

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, layout

I'd added a cart link to my magento site as:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout">
    <label>Cart</label>
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl"/>
    <title>Cart</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>150</position>
</action>
```

But I want to display an icon instead of `label` *cart*. How could I add image in the above **xml** code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout">
    <label>Cart</label>
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl"/>
    <title>Cart</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>150</position>
    <liParams />
    <aParams><![CDATA[ class="cart"]]></aParams>
</action>
```

This should add a class "cart" to the `<a>` element. You can add your css on that class that hides the text and displays an icon.

Comment: this is more easy way to add image :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

With the use of this code you can add image in xml file.

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout">
    <label>
    <![CDATA[<div style="position: absolute;"><img id="imgid" src="" alt="" border="0" style="padding-right:5px;"/>your Label</div>&nbsp;
    <script>
        var n = SKIN_URL.indexOf("frontend");
        $('imgid').src = SKIN_URL.substring(0, n) + "default/default/images/yourimagename.png";
    </script>]]>
    </label>
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl"/>
    <title>Cart</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>150</position>
</action>
```